# Conjugation in Early Modern English for "Their"

Tags: british-english, early-modern-english, seventeenth-century-english

I am writing a script set in England 1608 17th century. I am having trouble conjugating.

1. "Their desesperation maketh them a threat?"
   I though this sentence was well conjugated at first, but then I found this table that says that -eth is only for 3rd Personal Singular and NOT Plural.

Help me.

[image]

Comment: Please put answers in the answer box, not the comment box.